# Extending the RangeAttribute in MVC 2 (DataAnnotations namespace) to have a variable date range based on today's date

Tags: model-view-controller, attributes, range

Has anyone extended the Range attribute to be able to have a variable range?

I have a similar need but I can't make this work:

```
public class YearRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
    {
        public YearRangeAttribute()
            : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100).Year.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(-14).Year.ToString()) { }

    }
```

There is nothing on the page when it is rendered to the browser.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

```
# public class YearRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute  
#    {  
#          
#   
#   
#        public YearRangeAttribute()  
#           : base(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100).Year, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-16).Year) { }  
#                 
#          
#              
#    }
```

and on the Global.asax.cs:

```
   DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(YearRangeAttribute), typeof(RangeAttributeAdapter));
```

Cheers

Lizet

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you had to register in Global file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working example:

```
public class PermittedYearRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public PermittedYearRangeAttribute()
        : base(1900, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-50).Year)
    {
        ErrorMessage = string.Format("Year must be between 1900 and {0}", DateTime.Now.AddYears(-50).Year);
    }
}
```

In `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start()` method add following line

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(PermittedYearRangeAttribute), typeof(RangeAttributeAdapter));
```

In Model Decorate property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter year")]
[PermittedYearRange]
public int Year { get; set; }
```

Html rendered:

```
 <input class="tooltip form-control input dob--input input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Year must be a number." data-val-range="Year must be between 1900 and 1965" data-val-range-max="1965" data-val-range-min="1900" data-val-required="Please enter year" id="Year" maxlength="4096" name="Year" placeholder="YYYY" tabindex="" type="text" value="0">
```